# Alfresco Fileupload during workflow

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

How can I have file upload property during workflow in my model file?

I have use alfresco 4.2 version. I like to add property for fileupload in below code which allow user to upload file during workflow.

```
<type name="iabookwf:createProjectSizingTask">
    <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
    <properties>
        <property name="iabookwf:mandays">
            <title>Estimated Man Days</title>
            <type>d:int</type>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </property>
        <property name="iabookwf:totalCost">
            <title>Total Estimated Cost</title>
            <type>d:double</type>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <overrides>
        <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
            <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
        </property>
    </overrides>
    <mandatory-aspects>
        <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect>
    </mandatory-aspects>
</type>
```

Comment: If you've been through previous examples and have struggled at particular points please highlight what you have tried and where issues have arisen. SO is not the place to explain whole topics, such as in this case, all of Activiti workflow configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply actully in your post https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/upload-file-during-wofklow-12072011-0823#p128862 so it is not useful.                                                          the discussion on the source code which is removed on which the discussion done. http://www.sendspace.com/file/3arndk  http://www.2shared.com/file/-iY4mBWY/2012_05_25_POC_Add_Files_In_Wo.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add a site-webscript form control that utilizes the alfresco/components/upload/ components. The way to achieve this is to add a Share module extension, which will load the upload components onto the Tasks page or template. Then override the alfresco form control, via the web-extensions directory to include the Upload button on the Form control for associations.

In addition to the Upload button, you will need to add an upload handler so that Alfresco knows how to handle the newly uploaded file. Generally this can go into a workflow site, a workflow directory, dedicated for workflow items, etc. You can copy/paste and extend the alfresco's upload.post.* webscripts and modify them for your own use. However, regardless of where the newly uploaded files go, the user accessing the workflow, must have permissions to access the file, otherwise the associated entry will be blank for that user.

Here is a screenshot of a typical project layout:
[image: A typical layout of an Alfresco Share Extension Module]

Once your form controls are in place, edit the share-config-custom.xml to define the form used in your workflow, and override the form entry for that control, to use your new control.
**share-config-custom.xml**

```
<alfresco-config>
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$activitiAdhoc">
    <forms>
        <form>

            <appearance>
                <field id="packageItems">
                    <control >
                        <control-param name="allowUpload">true</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
            </appearance>

        </form>

    </forms>

</config>
```

For a working example, you can see may visit my [blog on this feature](http://swazzy.com/alfresco-workflow-form-with-upload-functionality/) which includes source codes for an Alfresco Enterprise Maven Project.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am begginer in alfresco. In my project this requirement arise. Please provide some code or any link or forum so I can further procced in this issue.

Comment: @alex: thanks, your source codes saved much of my time.